# How to increase splash counts besides upgrading angelic radiance?

Tags: tap-titans-2

My angelic radiance requires 5 skill points per upgrade and will only increase my splash count by 2

I have +14 splash count due to angelic radiance.

Yet I have 23 splash count.

How to improve that further?

I got tons of splash skip though but those are useless because the splash skip is higher than number of titans on my maximum stage.

Answer (score 1):

For "Heavenly Strike" splash count, there are a total of 3 ways to increase the numbers of stages you splash through:

1. Angelic Radiance in your skill tree
2. Snap effect
3. Angelic Guardian mythical set

With all 3 combined, you can splash 70 stages if I am not mistaken (splashed 63 with Angelic Radience level 24 + snap effect + Angelic Guardian set)

Answer (score -1):

After researching the topic, it seems that according to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TapTitans2/comments/b63f7l/how_do_i_increase_my_max_splash_count_i_feel_like/) the only way is through Angelic radience. The only other thing that somewhat counts, is that "If you want to increase your Clan Ship Splash Count though, you can also level up Aerial Assault in the Warlord tree."

Comment: Definitly not the only way